# Alternate solution to using variable in resources/repositories/repository/ref

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to find an alternate solution to using variable in resources/repositories/repository/ref because using a variable is technically not allowed.
resources:

```
resources:      
  repositories: 
  - repository: devops
    name: MyProjects/devops
    type: git 
    ref: master
```

The workaround of doing a git clone of the external repository will not work for me because my dependency on that repository is for referencing the templates.

Example:

```
 - template: Build/Templates/downloadFiles.yaml@devops
```

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you for reading my post!